# Clipping of lines in Graphics, fitting with AxesLabel

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a Graphics which is a combination of several plots, lines, text and the like. Some of the features lie outside of PlotRange and that is ok for me. I rely on proper clipping of those things outside of `PlotRange`. At the end I used `AxesLabel->{“X”,”Y”}` to put labels to the axes.

Now I see that the axes labels are properly placed and especially the Y-axis is shortened to accommodate space for the label "Y". However all the other lines which extend to places outside of the Graphics are not clipped at the same Y-level, they rather extend beyond the automatically chosen end of the Y-scale. That does not look as pretty as I want it.

**How can I easily clip everything above a given Y-coordinate in my Plot?**

One more question: **How can I achieve to attach arrows on the ends of my plotted axes?**

Answer (score 1):

Just add the option `PlotRangeClipping -> True`.
In order to plot Arrowheads to the axes, juat add to Graphics the options

```
Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}], AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}
```

Bingo!